# Multiple NPN driving single PNP

Tags: transistors, ac, opto-isolator

In my circuit I have multiple NPN collectors tied together driving a single PNP which turns on a ATTINY10 anytime the Optocouplers turn on.

The logic I want is:

Optocoupler turns on, indicator LED only for that optocoupler turns on.

If 1 or more optocouplers is on, PNP turns on.

When all optocouplers are off, no 5V to ATTINY.

Will this circuit work the way I think it is?
[image]

Comment: >Will this circuit work the way I think it is? < No.. Opto=off means collector is high, also PNP have reversed CE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work after these modifications:

1. Swap emitter and collector of Q5 (same bug as in your last circuit)
2. Use diodes between the HEAT outputs of the couplers and the summing point HEAT near Q5. Connect the cathodes to the coupler sides and all anodes to R44. If you don't use diodes, all LEDs at the couplers are simply parallel and one coupler must be able drive all LEDs.
3. As long as the Tiny has no supply, Q4 is not conducting. So you can connect the load side components of Q4 directly to +5V (LED, D4, Relay) because there is no current consumption in this state. Just control VCC of the Tiny via Q5, the relay current should not flow through Q5.
4. Connect a bypass capacitor of 100nF between VCC and GND of the Tiny.
5. It should be enough to have only one 47 uF capacitor parallel to R44, there is no need to have one at each coupler output.
6. There may exist a problem with power on reset of the Tiny. Q5 is turning on slowly here and the internal reset of the Tiny does not work always at slow rising supply voltages. Using the BOD fuse can help there.

Hint: It is much better to let the Tiny run in sleep mode and use the "wakeup by interrupt" feature. The current consumption in a well configured sleep mode can be below 1 uA, far below 1% of the current the power LED needs.